# How to trigger a Twig Extension function from a twig variables content

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to be able to pass into twig some html in a variable and render it as

```
{{ data.content | raw }}
```

But within that content variable I would like to be able to have content like this - pulled from a database:

```
<div>
    <p>Text with a Twig Extension function call eg: {{ doSomething('112233') }}</p>
</div>
```

Is there any way to get that twig extension to fire having come from the Twig variable itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is one possible solution. Look at [template_from_string twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html). It says:

> New in version 1.11: The template_from_string function was added in Twig 1.11.
>
> The template_from_string function loads a template from a string:

```
{{ include(template_from_string(data.content)) }}
```

But doc also says:

> The template_from_string function is not available by default. You must add the Twig_Extension_StringLoader extension explicitly when creating your Twig environment.

So, probably it won't work out of box.